# Split up long list of 100 values to a list with small arrays of 10 values in it, python

Tags: python

I have a list of 100 values that i would like to split up to a list with arrays in it were every array holds 10 values.

## What I have, for ex:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8............]
```

## What I want, for ex:

```
newarray = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1],[2,3,4,5,6,7,8............]]
```

I want to do this so that I can call for newArray[4] and get 10 values.

This is what i have tried:

```
for i in range(len(values)):
    a = []
    for j in range(10): 
        a.append(values[j])
    val.append(a)

    print(val)
```

Problem is that i now get all the first ten values in every different array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are always appending the first ten elements since you're using `range(10)`. You can change the inner `for` loop to `a.append(values[i*10+j])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: that worked! @pault thanks!!

Comment: if i try to print (val) outside the for loop i get "list index out of range" do you know why this is? @pault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other (arguably more pythonic) ways to solve this problem, but here is what's wrong with *your* code:

In this part:

```
...
    for j in range(10): 
        a.append(values[j])
...
```

The index `j` will be the same for each value of `i`. The value you want to append, should be offset based on `i`.

Here is one approach:

```
...
    for j in range(10): 
        a.append(values[(i*10)+j])
...
```

This way when `i = 0`, you'll append the items from `values[0]` through `values[9]`. Likewise, when `i=1`, you'll append the items from `values[10]` through `values[19]` and so on.

Comment: if i try to print (val) outside the for loop i get "list index out of range" do you know why this is?

Comment: @Thosc1 it's hard to tell without seeing how  you defined `val`. I assumed you had initialized it to an empty list before the `for` loop. Please either [edit] this question or ask a new one, but in either case make sure to include the full code and the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using list comprehensions:

```
[array[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(array)-9, 10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only getting the first ten values is that you're only iterating over the first ten values, just for `len(values)` iterations. So, instead of ending up with a list of 10 sublists, each with 10 values, you get a list with 100 sublists, each with the first 10 values of the original list. To fix this, you need to change your outer loop variable to be `range(0, len(values) - 10, 10)` and your inner variable to be `range(i, i + 10)`. Of course, then you could be left with a little chunk at the end which you'd have to deal with, but in your case `len(values) % 10 == 0` so you should be fine there. Putting this all together, we have:

```
val = []
for i in range(0, len(values) - 10, 10):
    val.append(values[i: i + 10])
```

Doing this via list-comprehension:

```
val = [ values[i : i + 10] for i in range(0, len(values) - 10, 10) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version with 2 function, one is generator and the second one that creates a new list. Both of them uses generics.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import TypeVar


ChunkItem = TypeVar("ChunkItem")


def generate_chunks(
    items: list[ChunkItem], size: int
) -> Iterator[list[ChunkItem]]:
    for i in range(0, len(items), size):
        if chunk_records := items[i: i + size]:
            yield chunk_records


def make_chunks(items: list[ChunkItem], size: int) -> list[list[ChunkItem]]:
    return [
        items[size * i : size * i + size]
        for i in range(len(items) // size + 1)
        if items[
            size * i: size * i + size
        ]
    ]
```